# Debugging issue with Visual Studio 2022 in a Blazor WebAssembly project with Identity

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, browser, blazor, mozilla

I am experiencing an issue when debugging my Blazor WebAssembly project with Identity in Visual Studio 2022. The debugger works correctly when I set breakpoints on the client or server side, but when I click on the Register or Login links, the debugger stops. The Register or Login links work correctly when launched without debugging. The identification system is the default one provided.

Why does the debugger stop when I click on the Register or Login links?

**add information**
even clicking on About the debugger stops

**solution partially solved** by installing Mozilla it works
So the problem comes from chrome and Edge browser.

*What do I do to make it work for other browsers?*

**Solution:** I removed all the breakpoints

**cause of problem:** I added a console project to my program and I put a breakpoint in console program.

*I think there is a bug*

Comment: An exception thrown when you click the links?

Comment: @Maciek No, the debugger stops it's as if you stopped